# How to add multiple objective functions to optimization problem using PuLP?

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to solve optimization problem (Transportation problem is a closest type) using PuLP in Python.

Conditions:

- 5 shops producing output in 12 months
- Each shop must produce exact amount of output in a year (the annual output constraint for each shop)
- Sum of output for all shops in each month is also fixed (the monthly output constraint for all shops)
- Each shop has its own capacity (240 items per month for 4 of them and 60 items per month for 1)

It would be easier to understand the problem by looking on the following table:

[image: Optimization problem conditions]

In here you can see 5 shops and 12 months. 1st columns shows the annual output constraint for each shop. 1st row shows monthly output constraint for all shops. 'NaN' values are to find out with optimization. Basically, we need to fill values, so the column sum and row sum would meet the constraints.

**There is another important constraint:** we need to maximize amount of shops which are not producing for each month. In other words we need as much zeroes as it can be to still meet the constraints.

I found a solution for that problem in the following code:

```
# List of shops
shops = ([str(x) for x in df.index.tolist()[1:]])

# Dict of capacity for each shop
shops_prod = {x:y for x,y in zip(shops, df.iloc[1:,0])}

# List of months
months = df.columns[1:].tolist()

# Dict of capacity for each month
months_prod = {x:y for x,y in zip(months, df.iloc[0,1:])}
    
# Prob 
prob = LpProblem("Optimization_distribution", LpMinimize)

# Create all by all pairs 
routes = [(s, m) for s in shops for m in months]

# dict for 4 + 1 variables
vars = LpVariable.dicts("distribution", ([shops[0]] + shops[2:], months), 0, 240, LpContinuous)
vars.update(LpVariable.dicts("distribution", (shops[1], months), 0, 60, LpContinuous))

# Dict for zeroes
zero_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Zeroes",(shops, months), 0, 1, LpInteger)
a_very_large_number = sum(months_prod.values())


# Obj function
prob += (
    lpSum([zero_vars[s][m] for (s, m) in routes]),
    "Sum of zeroes",
)

# Shops capacity constraint
for s in shops:
    prob += (
        lpSum([vars[s][m] for m in months]) == shops_prod[s],
        f"Shop capacity: {s}",
    )

# Month capacity constraints
for m in months:
    prob += (
        lpSum([vars[s][m] for s in shops]) == months_prod[m],
        f"Month capacity: {m}",
    )

# Constraint for zeroes
for (s, m) in routes:
    prob += a_very_large_number * zero_vars[s][m] >= vars[s][m]

    

prob.writeLP("Optimization_distribution.lp")


prob.solve()

print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
```

That gives me result:
[image: Result of optimization]

**However, now I have another constraint:**
I need to minimize standard deviation of defective output throughout the year between all shops.
I don't need to minimize sum of defective output, but I need to flatten the percentage of it throughout the year.

So, I have defective output rate for each shop:

[image: Defective rate]

I need to minimize standard deviation of sum of output per month multiplied by defective rate for each shop respectively.

I tried to set a constraint:

```
for m in months:
    prob += np.std(
        sum([(vars[s][m] * defective_rate[s]) for s in shops ])
    ) == 0
```

But that gives me an error:  `AttributeError: 'LpAffineExpression' object has no attribute 'conjugate'`

Tried to google it, and find out that PuLP doesn't really "like" `numpy` package

Because I have lack of experience with PuLP, I am stuck. Would be thankful to get any ideas!

It also would be great to get any links to proper PuLP tutorial

P.S
Sorry for any language mistakes, English is not my native language

Comment: `std()` is non-linear operation, so it cannot be used.  One common alternative is to employ a 'mini-max' strategy where you minimize the maximum number of defective items per shop, essentially flattening out the deviations.  Here is an example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76085260/define-constraints-with-or-tools-for-a-carpooling-problem/76088196#76088196

Comment: You could gin up a mini-max and then make your objective function a weighted sum of the zero count and the max defects by shop, with some fiddling with the weights.